# How do i replace string in yaml file in groovy?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml

samle jules.yaml file:

```
sealId: 222222
node: java-11 && maven-3 
baseVersion: 1.0.0
aws:
  endpointType: codedeploy
  appspec: 
mapping:
  - name: master
    awsDeployment:
      - env: dev
        accountId: '122121212'
        regions:
          - region: us-east-1
            codedeploy:
              - application: cdp-agent-codedeploy
                deploymentGroup: cdp-agent-codedeploy-gp
```

I need to replace application and deployment group with different value. I tried like below but no luck

my Jenkins file code:

```
julesnew = readYaml file: "jules.yml"
       
          julesnew.mapping[0].awsDeployment.env[0].regions[0].codedeploy.deploymentGroup ="new-deploymentgroup"

writeYaml file: 'juels-new.yaml', data: julesnew
          sh "cat juels-new.yaml"
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is correct, but you need to **properly navigate the original YAML structure**. I think you need

```
julesnew.mapping[0].awsDeployment[0].regions[0].codedeploy[0].deploymentGroup = "new-deploymentgroup"
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28379726)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was a liitle too quick here : )

Comment: Updated the answer with complete instructions to fix.